# Menu navigation wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I´m working on a wordpress site with 2 diffrent sections (landingpage that link to private or corporate). The sections have diffrent menu navigation buttons. Do I have to install 2 separate wp-installations or is there any better way to solve the navigation issue?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install wordpress twice. To present some menu you can use

`wp_nav_menu()` function (see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu).

So in different files of your theme you can use:

`<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'menu1' )); ?>`
and
`<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'menu2' )); ?>`

Than, you have to create 2 menu1 and menu2 in the Appearance → Menus panel.

Comment: HI! I was thinking about that..But when the "client" is adding new pages..hm.. How to get the right navigation to page/section?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem. He will add a new page and put it only in menu1 and not in menu2, so it will appear only on private site menu. But you (or your client) should take a care not to show all the categories or all the pages, because, if so, the visitors of private site will see the pages of corporate one.